# Infinity - Infinity indetermination in limits

Tags: limits

How can I solve this?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} 2x - e ^{x - 1}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: You can breka the term $(2x-e^{x-1}) = e^{x-1}(\frac{2x}{e^{x-1}}-1)$ then apply the limits on these two terms separately thus we get:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{x-1}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\frac{2x}{e^{x-1}}-1\bigg)=\infty \times (-1)=-\infty$$

Comment: @user551915 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} 2x - e ^{x - 1}=\lim_{x \to \infty} 2x\left(1 - \frac{e ^{x - 1}}{2x}\right)=(+\infty\cdot -\infty)=-\infty$$

indeed eventually $e^{x-1}\ge x^2$ and thus

$$\frac{e ^{x - 1}}{2x}\ge\frac{x^2}{2x}=\frac x 2 \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $[x-1]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x-1.$ We have   $x-1\geq[x-1]>x-2.$ We have $e>2.$  By the Binomial Theorem we  have $$x\geq 3\implies e^{x-1}>2^{x-1}\geq 2^{[x-1]}=(1+1)^{[x-1]}=$$ $$=\binom {[x-1]}{0}+\binom {[x-1]}{1}+\binom {[x-1]}{2}+....\;>$$ $$>\binom {[x-1]}{2}=$$ $$=\frac {[x-1]([x-1]-1)}{2}>$$ $$> \frac {(x-2)(x-3)}{2}.$$ Therefore $x\geq 3\implies 2x-e^{x-1}<2x- \frac {(x-2)(x-3)}{2}.$

Comment: Exponential growth will  overtake any polynomial growth if you wait long enough.